# PHP switch statement doesn't executes values using return

Tags: php, switch-statement, return

Is it possible that PHP switch statement does not executes the switch desired result while using return?

What is the difference between these two statements?

```
$foo = '2';    
switch ($foo) {       
    case 1:
        echo 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        echo 2;
        break;
}
```

executes 2

versus

```
$foo = '2';    
switch ($foo) {       
    case 1:
        return 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        return 2;
        break;
}
```

Doesnt seem to work.

is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Are you inside a function ?

Comment: no, i have tested it on a blank new file.

Comment: If you aren't in a function, `return` should stop the execution of the file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php. Is it what's happening ?

Comment: tried to write '2' and '1'. nothing changed.  the reason i arrived to this issue is that the switch is inside a function, the thing is that i want the switch result to be returned and not achoed or printed.

Comment: @DavSev You have conflicting responses. In your first comment, you state that you are NOT in a function, using a blank new file. In your second response, you state that you are in a function. Which is it?

Comment: i had a problem with php switch statement in a function, i wanted to get to the bottom of the problem so i isolated the switch statement. than i found out that it still doesnt work. for this thred i will like to focus on why retun is not working inside the swich statement an how it can be activated .

Comment: Return ___does___ work in a switch statements.... [proof](http://3v4l.org/0Odpv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use a case statement in a function -

```
function myFunction($foo) {
    switch ($foo) {       
        case 1:
            return 1;


        case 2:
            return 2;


        default:
            return 'no matching values were sent to the function';

    }
}

echo myFunction(2); // will echo '2'
```

You should get in the habit of using default cases in your switches, even if you only use them to record an error to a log or something similar.

Comment: then remove the break statements

Comment: How is it "good practice" to add code that never runs and does not do anything whatsoever? This to me is entirely bad practice. I look at the return, then the break, then the return and think if I've missed something. Then walk away shaking my head at whichever dev did this utterly pointless thing.

Comment: Adding code that does absolutely nothing whatsoever in any circumstances is bad code, and teaching new devs such things is also bad. You are teaching them bad logical approaches. If junior has switch without break or return and shouldn't fall through, then the error is simply they should return, or set var and break. It's so so simple there's just no need to confuse them by complicating what is such as simple thing: Either return, use a var and break, or let fall through! - "get them into good coding habits even if sometimes those habits don't make sense" - this is just contradiction (sorry)

Comment: "like always coding breaks in a switch statement no matter the context." and what about the very legitimate context of "fall through" that has neither break or return? You're just confusing them by weird logic (sorry again am just being factual). Such ideas to try to not let them "slip up" is not good for people to learn from, especially with something simple they should grasp like a switch. If you can't teach a junior "break or return" in a switch then they're surely just going to struggle with so many deeper more advanced things?

Comment: From your answer text: "you do not need to have the break statements", and "even if you only use them to record an error to a log or something similar" neither of these make sense. In the first you agree it's pointless, but do it anyway. In the second, no logging or exception or ANYTHING will happen because there's a return. The break is pointless code. Confusing to some, annoying to others, and pointless to everyone

Answer (score 7):

The [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) outputs the value that you pass (1, 2)
The [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) passes the value to the calling module.

The second block of code does work, but you don't see any visual output.

Comment: How can i see the value of it while still using return?

Answer (score 0):

return works with functions.Second will execute if its inside a function