# PHP switch statement function in OOP function

Tags: php, oop, switch-statement, return

earlier today i asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811377/php-switch-statement-doesnt-executes-values-using-return/28811667#28811667) regarding retuning the output of a switch statement.

the conclusion was that return in a switch statement should be used only inside a function.

now i am trying to use the return in a Method in a Class. 
this is the code:

```
class ClassName{

     public function www($foo)
     {
        switch ($foo) {       
            case 1:
                return '1';
                break;

            case 2:
                return '2';
                break;

            default:
                return 'no matching values were sent to the function';
                break;
        }
    }
}

$foo = 2;
ClassName::www($foo);
```

when i replace the return with echo i get an output. 
why it dosnt work with return?

Comment: Along with the answer, you don't need those `break`s since return exits the switch and function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` literally returns the value to the calling code, you have to actually do something with it:

```
echo ClassName::www($foo);
//or
$val = ClassName::www($foo);
echo $val * 4;
```